# Does JavaScript regex matching require repeated code?

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following regex code snippet in Perl:

```
if ($message =~ /^(.+) enters the race!$/)) {
    $racer = $1;
    print "Found $racer";
} else {
    print "Racer parsing error!";
}
```

I'm trying to port this to JavaScript, and here's what I have come up with:

```
if (message.match(/^.+ enters the race!$/)) {
    var racer = message.match(/^(.+) enters the race!$/)[1];
    console.log("Found " + racer);
} else {
    console.log("Racer parsing error!");
}
```

Notice how the regex has to be repeated twice. This look sloppy. Not to mention that it wastes processing power since it has to do the same regex twice in a row. Is there any way to make this code snippet look cleaner?

Comment: Might as well just do `if (racer = message.match(/^(.+) enters the race!$/)[1] ) { ..} else { ..}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences between the code you have in Perl and JS:

- JS does not have string interpolation, so your code has to be a bit verbose
- There are no `$1`-like global variables, though you can declare it and use in code.

You can first match and check if the regex matched anything.

```js
var message = "John enters the race!";
var m = message.match(/^(.+) enters the race!$/); // Match the string with a pattern
if (m) {                                          // Check if there is a match
    var racer = m[1];                             // Assign the captured substring to `racer`
    console.log("Found " + racer);              
} else {
    console.log("Racer parsing error!");
}
```

Note that `m` here is a Match object containing:

- `m[0]` - the whole matched text
- `m[1]` - the contents of Group 1 (capture group 1)
- `m.index` -  the 0-based index of the match in the string
- `m.input` - the original string

Answer (score 2):

You can check the regex match right in the if statement.  Something like this would work:

**JavaScript**

```
function check(message) {
    if (racer = message.match(/^(.+) enters the race!$/)) {
    console.log("Found " + racer[1]);
    } else {
    console.log("Racer parsing error!");
    }
}


check("blah enters the race!")
check("blah blah blah")
```

**Output**

> Found blah
>   Racer parsing error!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if the capture group is empty, there is no regex match and the else statement is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the match result in a variable:

```
var result = message.match(/^.+ enters the race!$/);
if (result) {
    var racer = result[1];
    console.log("Found " + racer);
} else {
    console.log("Racer parsing error!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the match command once. If it fails, `getmatches` will be null. If it's successful, `getmatches[1]` will contain your racer's name

```js
var rgx = /^(.+) enters the race!$/,
  message = window.prompt('Enter Message'),
  getmatches = message.match(rgx);
if (getmatches) {
  var racer = getmatches[1];
  console.log("Found " + racer);
} else {
  console.log("Racer parsing error!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a `RegExp` instance and use `test()` and `exec()` methods as follows:

```
var myRegExp = new RegExp('^(.+) enters the race!$');

var message = 'Someone enters the race!';

if (myRegExp.test(message)) {
  var racer = myRegExp.exec(message)[1];
  console.log('Found ' + racer);
} 
else {
  console.log('Racer parsing error!');
}
```

Note the usage of `(` and `)` in the regular expression.